# "HashMap$Entry cannot be cast to X" when trying to extract values from Map with a loop

Tags: java, list, hashmap

```
public class CarService implements ICarService {
private final Map<String, Car> carMap = new HashMap<String, Car>();

@Override
public List<Car> findAll() {
    final ArrayList<Car> al = new ArrayList<Car>();
    for (final Map.Entry<String, Car> entry : carMap.entrySet()) {
        al.add((Car) entry);
    }
    return al;
}
}
```

I have a Class name CarService where it will get all the info from carMap and store into List. However I get error indicated that "java.util.HashMap$Entry cannot be cast to Car"

```
final CarService carSvc = new CarService();
List<Car> getAllCar = new ArrayList<>();
getAllCar = carSvc.findAll();
System.out.println(getAllCar.size());
```

this is my main function that calling car service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your `for` loop.

```
for (final Map.Entry<String, Car> entry : carMap.entrySet()) {
    al.add((Car) entry);
}
```

Here, you declare `entry` as a `Map.Entry<String, Car>`.  You can't cast that to `Car` in any way.  You will need to get the *value* of that `Map.Entry` and add it to `a1`.

You can do this using the [`getValue()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getValue%28%29).  e.g.,

```
for(final Map.Entry<String, Car> entry : carMap.entrySet()) {
    a1.add(entry.getValue());
}
```

No need for casting at all, in the end, thanks to your type parameters.

Comment: @user3555283 Glad it helped you out. :)  Best of luck.

Comment: Good job taking time on the explanation - this is often skipped.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out the original code results in a run-time error because a Map.Entry object isn't a Car (so the cast is invalid).

That being said, since the keys are not required then [Map#values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29) can be used,

```
for (final Car car : carMap.values()) {
    al.add(car);
}
```

Or, "No loops Ma!"

```
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>(carMap.values());
```

Comment: Nice point.  I'm used to doing some kind of filtering based on the key, so I didn't even look to question that.  Haha  +1

Comment: Nice solution too..Simple and ease to understand. Thanks user2864740

Answer (score 2):

Why not be simple about it?:

```
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>(carMap.values());
```

`HashMap#values()` returns a `Collection<T>` which you can then supply directly to the ArrayList constructor.

Comment: user2864740 managed to edit it in JUST before you posted it. :(

Comment: Mine's got the Java 7 diamond syntax ;)